401 Invalid_client from Powerschool API
Code I am using:
def get_access_token():
    url = f'https://powerschool.rva.org/oauth/access_token'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',

    }
    data = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET

    }

    print(f"Request URL: {url}")
    print(f"Headers: {headers}")
    print(f"Data: {data}")  # Be cautious printing secrets in production

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(f"Response Status Code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response Text: {response.text}")
    if response.status_code == 200:
        token_data = response.json()
        return token_data['access_token']
    else:
        print(f"Error getting access token: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
        return None

When I run the above code, I get a 401 invalid_client error back from Powerschool, does anyone know why?
I have confirmed that the client ID and client secret are correct from my PowerSchool instance
My current plugin in powerschool is the basic example plugin provided:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://plugin.powerschool.pearson.com"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation='http://plugin.powerschool.pearson.com plugin.xsd'
        name="(Your Product Name)"
        version="(Your Product Version)"
        description="The plugin for PowerSchool integration with (Your Product Name)">
    <oauth></oauth> 
    <publisher name="(Your Company Name)">
        <contact email="(Your Email Address)" />
    </publisher>
    <access_request>
        <field table="CodeSet" field="description" access="ViewOnly" />
        <field table="CodeSet" field="codetype" access="ViewOnly" />
        <field table="CodeSet" field="codesetid" access="ViewOnly" />
        <field table="CodeSet" field="code" access="ViewOnly" />

        <field table="STUDENTS" field="DCID" access="ViewOnly" />
        <field table="STUDENTS" field="ID" access="ViewOnly" />
        <field table="STUDENTS" field="first_name" access="ViewOnly" />
        <field table="STUDENTS" field="last_name" access="ViewOnly" />
        <field table="STUDENTS" field="grade_level" access="ViewOnly" />

        <field table="TRANSPORTATION" field="DCID" access="FullAccess" />
        <field table="TRANSPORTATION" field="ID" access="FullAccess" />
        <field table="TRANSPORTATION" field="StudentId" access="FullAccess" />
        <field table="TRANSPORTATION" field="Description" access="FullAccess" />
        
    </access_request>
</plugin>

As far as I am aware, this should not matter as I am just trying to generate an OAuth token from the powerschool API
I've tried a number of refactors, as I was getting a missing grant type previously which was resolved by changing the content type from application-json to it's current form
